# Creating a custom title bar in Android with a search feature

Tags: android

I'm very new to Android development and am still struggling with some really basic things. One of the things that I haven't been able to figure out is how to create a custom title bar for application with the Holo Light theme.

[image]

I'd like to place a search button as depicted in the first image, which when clicked, opens a little text area to type the search query as shown in the second image.

Although this question seems to have been posted many times over, it seems to be for the older Android versions. Explaining how I could do this or and example would be a good push in the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it.

http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-development/action-bar-search-view/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use: [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/)